# Invalid nested tag head found

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm trying to convert a webpage to PDF using VB.NET and iTextSharp. I tried so many different examples and nothing seems to be working (for me at least). This is the closest I got, but the XMLWorkerHelper always throws the exception `Invalid nested tag head found, expected closing tag script`, no matter which web page is parsed.

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient      
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://google.com")        
Dim doc As New Document(PageSize.A4)
Dim writer As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, New System.IO.FileStream("c:\test.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
Dim sr As New System.IO.StringReader(result)
Try
    XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, sr)
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I'm using iTextSharp 5.4.2.0 and .NET Framework 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var HtmlNode = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlNode.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
HtmlNode.Save(your directory); // save a new HTML file converted
```

then convert from the new HTML.